# save current date into database

Tags: android, date

I want to save system date on my database, but it returns : `22/0/2013`.
here my code :

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 

               int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
               int month_ = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
               int day_ = cal.get(Calendar.DATE);

               String  FullDate = (""+day_+"/"+month_+"/"+year);

                String text_Rate=(String.valueOf(FullDate));                                
                Log.d("System Date show", text_Rate);
```

where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: There is a good discussion of working with dates in database here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653818/how-to-get-day-month-and-year-from-datepickerdialog/11674998#11674998

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. [The Java `Calendar` month is 0-based (January is 0, December is 11)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344380/why-is-january-month-0-in-java-calendar).

If you really want to store it as `22/1/2013`, simply add `+1` to your month:

```
int month_ = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

you should save dates as long to sqlite. that is easier and less prone to errors. see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime%28%29) for calendar to long.